# RelationPredicateBucket doesn't filter mocked data for Unit Test on Repository GetAllActive() call

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, repository, moq

I am trying to Test a function which I have below to get all active categories which will use a relation predicate bucket. The mocked data in the initializer class adds three objects which are both active and not deleted. It adds a fourth to the end which is deleted and not active.

During the test, the call will return all four objects, and not the expected number of three. This is where I am stuck with.

I have tried making `_randomCategories` as a Queryable object, but this also failed.

There is a lot of code in the first class so it may be hard to follow, so each part is broken into regions saying which part it performs, i.e. Test Setup, Mock Data, & the Tests themselves.

The Mock Data region are the expected results. May not be necessary for my needs here as it is not used in this other than to get the expected count, but it may be relevant to the overall structure of the tests.

**CategoryServiceTests.cs**

```
#region Test Setup

public class CategoryServiceFixture : IDisposable
{
    public CategoryService Sut { get; private set; }
    private SystemRepository SystemRepository { get; set; }
    private Mock<CategoryRepository> _categoryRepositoryMock;
    private List<CategoryEntity> _randomCategories;

    public CategoryServiceFixture()
    {
        // Init Category List
        _randomCategories = CategoryEntityInitializer.GetAllMockCategories();

        // Init repository
        _categoryRepositoryMock = new Mock<CategoryRepository>(new object[] { null });

        // Setup mocking behavior            
        // BaseRepository
        _categoryRepositoryMock
            .Setup(m => m.GetAll(It.IsAny<IRelationPredicateBucket>(), It.IsAny<IDataAccessAdapter>()))
            .Returns(_randomCategories);

        SystemRepository = new SystemRepository(category: _categoryRepositoryMock.Object);
        Sut = new CategoryService(this.SystemRepository);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //Sut.Dispose();
    }
}

[CollectionDefinition("CategoryService Collection")]
public class CategoryServiceCollection : ICollectionFixture<CategoryServiceFixture> { }

#endregion

#region Mock Data

public static class CategoryRepositoryMockData
{
    public static IEnumerable<object> GetCategories
    {
        get
        {
            yield return new object[] { 1, new List<CategoryEntity>() {
                new CategoryEntity
                {
                    CategoryId = 1,
                    Name = "Test1",
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    IsActive = true
                },
                new CategoryEntity
                {
                    CategoryId = 2,
                    Name = "Test2",
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    IsActive = true
                },
                new CategoryEntity
                {
                    CategoryId = 3,
                    Name = "Test3",
                    IsDeleted = false,
                    IsActive = true
                }
            }};
        }
    }
}

#endregion

#region Tests

[Collection("CategoryService Collection")]
public class CategoryServiceTests
{
    private CategoryServiceFixture _fixture;

    public CategoryServiceTests(CategoryServiceFixture fixture)
    {
        _fixture = fixture;
    }

    [Theory]
    [Trait("Category", "Get All Active Categories")]
    [Trait("Expected", "Return Correct")]
    [MemberData("GetCategories", MemberType = typeof(CategoryRepositoryMockData))]
    public void GetActiveCategories_ShouldReturn(int id, IList<CategoryEntity> expectedCategoryObjects)
    {
        var result = _fixture.Sut.GetActiveCategories();
        Assert.Equal(expectedCategoryObjects.Count, result.Count);
    }
}

#endregion
```

This class generates the mock database objects. This is what is supposed to be searched through and select the correct ones from the list.

**CategoryEntityInitializer.cs**

```
public static class CategoryEntityInitializer
{
    public static List<CategoryEntity> GetAllMockCategories()
    {
        List<CategoryEntity> _categories = new List<CategoryEntity>();

        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            var entity = new CategoryEntity()
            {
                CategoryId = i,
                Name = String.Format("{0}{1}", "Test", i),
                IsDeleted = false,
                IsActive = true
            };

            _categories.Add(entity);
        }

        var lastEntity = new CategoryEntity()
        {
            CategoryId = 4,
            Name = String.Format("{0}{1}", "Test", 4),
            IsDeleted = true,
            IsActive = false
        };

        _categories.Add(lastEntity);

        return _categories;
    }
}
```

This class is where the predicate is.

**CategoryService.cs**

```
public class CategoryService : BaseService
{
    public IList<CategoryModel> GetActiveCategories()
    {
        var bucket = new RelationPredicateBucket();
        bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(CategoryFields.IsDeleted == false);
        bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(CategoryFields.IsActive == true);
        var categoriesEntities = _systemRepository.Category.GetAll(bucket);
        return CategoryMapper.MapToModels(categoriesEntities);
    }
}
```

The rest of the code structure works fine for every other test and across different test classes. This is the first time I have had to test the relation predicate bucket.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE 18/05/16**

I found the solution to the problem. Answer in the below code.

```
_categoryRepositoryMock
    .Setup(m => m.GetAll(It.IsAny<IRelationPredicateBucket>(), It.IsAny<IDataAccessAdapter>()))
    .Returns(new Func<IRelationPredicateBucket, IDataAccessAdapter, IEnumerable<CategoryEntity>>(
        (bucket, adapter) => _randomCategories.Where(a => a.IsDeleted == false && a.IsActive == true)));
```

**Old Answer 11/05/16**

> I believe I have found part of the answer. In mocking the repository, I was returning all four objects, no matter if the predicate bucket would work or not.

```
_categoryRepositoryMock
    .Setup(m => m.GetAll(It.IsAny<IRelationPredicateBucket>(), It.IsAny<IDataAccessAdapter>()))
    .Returns(_randomCategories);
```

This will cause it to return all four as I have not implemented the bucket to filter out the matches. I thought that the `.Returns` would place the data into the repository as if returned from the database and then get filtered with the bucket.

What I have found out is that the call to the repository does not go to the one it would if it was running normally, but instead goes to the mocked repository and this is where you need to filter the data to be returned.

It needs to be done something similar to this.

```
_categoryRepositoryMock
    .Setup(m => m.GetAll(It.IsAny<IRelationPredicateBucket>(), It.IsAny<IDataAccessAdapter>()))
    .Returns(
        (IRelationPredicateBucket bucket) => _randomCategories.Where(x => x.Name.Equals(bucket)));
```

> Although this still give me a problem as I don't know how to get inside the bucket to match to the list, it is at least heading in the correct direction.

**NOTE:** I have also found from searching that another reason for this type of failure is due to the code, in this case the function being called is too complex to be tested. It should be seperated into smaller chucks to make it less complex and to test each part seperately.

**Before**

```
public class CategoryService : BaseService
{
    public IList<CategoryModel> GetActiveCategories()
    {
        var bucket = new RelationPredicateBucket();
        bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(CategoryFields.IsDeleted == false);
        bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(CategoryFields.IsActive == true);
        var categoriesEntities = _systemRepository.Category.GetAll(bucket);
        return CategoryMapper.MapToModels(categoriesEntities);
    }
}
```

**After**

```
public class CategoryService : BaseService
{
    public IList<CategoryModel> GetActiveCategories()
    {
        var bucket = GetActiveCategoriesBucket();
        var categoriesEntities = _systemRepository.Category.GetAll(bucket);
        return CategoryMapper.MapToModels(categoriesEntities);
    }

    public RelationPredicateBucket GetActiveCategoriesBucket()
    {
        var bucket = new RelationPredicateBucket();
        bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(CategoryFields.IsDeleted == false);
        bucket.PredicateExpression.Add(CategoryFields.IsActive == true);
        return bucket;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will update this answer once I figure out the complete solution to getting it to work.

Comment: Found the complete solution